# Does pwa uses browser cache if their is no service worker

Tags: ios, manifest, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, http-caching

I have an app written in js. I want to convert it to a pwa without a service worker . By adding manifest file I can add it from home screen and open it in full screen mode. Does it still using http caching If enabled or it will fetch request from network every time as I don’t have any service worker .
Secondly how can I provided updated change in manifest file to an already installed pwa in ios.

Comment: If there is no service worker, it's not a PWA (I believe) because it will not pass the PWA check with the chrome lighthouse tool.

Comment: More details here: https://web.dev/service-worker/?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=lr

Comment: understood Mathias . I also thought the same .what about http caching ?

Comment: I believe you need to have all the PWA pieces in place for your website to work offline